# Error: `Undefined control sequence` in a downloaded template

Tags: errors, templates, cv

I have downloaded a CV template from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/15285787kdynktzjxwxk#/57856196/), which uses `altacv.cls`. When I tried to compile `main.tex` using XeLaTeX it gives the following error followed by many others:

```
Undefined control sequence. \makecvheader
```

If someone can have look at the template, I would be thankful of him.

UPDATE: I have downloaded the complete project from [Github](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV) and tried running the `sample.tex` file but found the same error at line 89: `Undefined control sequence. \makecvheader`. I have provided a snapshot and the [sample.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WTxFdnWXM8Qway8UOOQE6kubO0XqI5Xn/view?usp=sharing) file
[image: snapshot]

Comment: can you show the .log file?

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Curriculum_Vitae Check Out the customizable layout section. I wouldn't use any predefined templates.

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/creativeCv is of course a template that might be better for you. No restrictions there ;-)

Comment: hello johannes, are you mistaken, the tex file contains 7 line code

Comment: @pkj I am not mistaken. That file does not put any limitations on formatting for you. You can decide and design as you want.

Comment: In its current state, the question cannot be answered. Even with a bounty.

Comment: why?***********

Comment: I downloaded the files as ZIP, decompressed it and ran XeLaTeX. No error.

Comment: why.. why.. why? I have downloaded zip file from github many times, run it; but it did not worked? I am using TeXstudio, which program are you using? Does it has to do anything with compiler? What should I try next?

Comment: I downloaded both projects from Overleaf and GitHub; neither produces errors upon compilation with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @pkj Please, add the log file.

Comment: TeX Live 2018 was released a few days ago. You should install it or do a MikTeX update. Many of your files are badly outdated, fontawesome included. `\makecvheader` is not undefined, the undefined command is `\faAt` from package fontawesome. Your editor is just unable to parse correctly. And you have never learned how to read the lof-file, which is basic.

Comment: thanks @Johannes_B, I have installed TeXLive and it has solved my problem, kindly provide your suggestion as answer and I would accept. By the way which lines of the log file pointed out the issue, that would help me learn log file.

Comment: The line with the error message. Read LaTeX for complete novices to learn more about reading the log file.

Comment: hi @Johannes_B, the question still qualifies for the bounty, would like to answer?

Comment: How to fix a similar error in overleaf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log file shows that the used distribution is outdated. With a decently recent LaTeX installation, the template will work just fine.

I recommend to read [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) (free ebook) to learn some LaTeX basics, including reading the log-file.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that this model is developed in several files in a **working folder**, the code you have tried to compile only contains the part of code that can be seen as example (sample.tex) that requires other files such as the **altacv class** which is not a standard class of latex **(but is included locally in the working folder)** . Here is the complete folder that you can download and compile without problems [GitHub Complete project template](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV).

I suggest that you always look for the **complete project** of the models since they are not developed under the **strict philosophy of open source**, in which you must be able to compile the document **from a single code**, some models intentionally **seek to hide or entangle the code**. And other times it's to avoid having too long a code, judge under your own experiences.

UPDATE: 
To simplify I erased the files that are not necesary to compile sample.tex but enfatizing the necessary files...

[image]

I get no errors

[image]

Comment: hello @leon, thanks for the suggestion. I have downloaded the project and tried running the `sample.tex` file but the same error at `line 89: Undefined control sequence. \makecvheader` any other suggestions? Is it working for you?

Comment: Is the whole project sitting in the same directory? If it is, it should be running: the command it's barfing on is defined in the altacv class.

Comment: Sorry for not providing any update, I was travelling and not accessible to my desktop. I could not run the sample file. I am providing a snapshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fUGGcxo13ptzyTyvGGcsWUBWjzZwvEAu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hi @leon, I have put bounty on this question, in case if you want to try again. Sorry but your answer did not solved my problem